# SQL Server : delete all entries automatically

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a windows 2008 R2 server with SQL Server 2008 R2.

I have a database that is populated every hour from a third party. The database has `datetime` column (sample : 2012-11-22 11:59:00.000).

I only need the data from the current day, and to stop the database filling up, I would like to delete all entries older than the current day automatically on a daily basis.

I have no idea where to start with this.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You can use trigger on inserting to delete the entries older than the day. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258254(v=sql.80).aspx about creating triggers

```
CREATE TRIGGER insDelete
ON yourTable
FOR INSERT
BEGIN
   delete from yourTable where datetimeColumn < getdate()-1
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [SQL Server Agent job](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190268.aspx) that runs a query to delete the entries you want on a specified schedule.